Matlab eig same matrix return different answer
I am using MATLAB's eig function.
I define Sxx and Sxx2 to be totally the same, but using the function eig to get the eigenvalues D and D2 they are different.
xt=Xnor';
Sxx=xt*Xnor/6299;
Sxx2=Xnor'*Xnor/6299;

D = eig(Sxx);
D2 = eig(Sxx2);

Sxx and Sxx2 value compare screenshot
I have checked the matrices Sxx and Sxx2, the values are all the same
but the D and D2's value seems like they contain a huge mistake
D and D2 value compare screenshot
Am I missing something?

What happens if you sort both arrays of eigenvalues? Are they still different?

Hi Hopan, what is Xnor?

@FedRo,@BillBokeey, Xnor is the data after Z-score I wanna do the Principal components analysis(PCA). I want to find out each feature's  loading vector. So that I cant sort the eigenvalues. And  the eigenvalues about each feature will very important.

are the vectors D and D2 the same but sorted once ascendent and the other one in descendent order?

I don’t know why D2 is sorted but D is not. You’re doing the same computations, it’s weird that MATLAB would select a different algorithm in one case, but this seem to be the case.

@FedRo only D2 is sorted ,D isn't, they are the same.

Maybe because you defined Sxx2=Xnor'*Xnor, this matrix is secretly being marked as symmetric, whereas the other one, because you used an intermediate step, is not? I did not know MATLAB kept such information, but it is possible!

Can you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] so we might be able to reproduce and diagnose the issue? It's hard to do from partial screenshots of data. Just using random data I can't get them to differ...

@ Cris Luengo
"...  it’s weird that MATLAB would select a different algorithm in one case ..."
This is not weird at all. In one case the code forces MATLAB to do a generic matrix multiply (result not guaranteed to be strictly symmetric/Hermitian):
xt=Xnor';
Sxx=xt*Xnor/6299; % symmetry not recognized, generic DGEMM() or ZGEMM() BLAS routine called.

In the other case the MATLAB parser recognizes the symmetry and calls a symmetric BLAS() matrix multiply routine which is a completely different routine (result guaranteed to be strictly symmetric/Hermitian).
Sxx2=Xnor'*Xnor/6299; % symmetry recognized by parser, DSYRK() or ZSYRK() BLAS routine called

So the background order of operations & calculations has changed in the symmetric case. One should expect that the results might be slightly different.
"... this matrix is secretly being marked as symmetric ..."
There is no such background marking in MATLAB variables. The eig() function itself is checking the input argument explicitly for symmetry before deciding which background routines to call. It is just that the DGEMM() or ZGEMM() results can often be slightly off and not strictly symmetric/Hermitian down to the last bit, whereas the DSYRK() or ZSYRK() results are guaranteed to be strictly symmetric/Hermitian down to the last bit (they only return a triangular result ... MATLAB copies the off-diagonal elements in the background to get the full result hence exact symmetry is preserved).
Sorting the results should reveal the answers to be very close to each other.
In general, I would advise not to explicitly form the transpose. Let MATLAB keep the strict symmetry when possible.
E.g., take a random matrix and see what happens
>> a = rand(100);
>> b1 = a'*a; % faster and strictly symmetric/Hermitian result
>> at = a';
>> b2 = at*a; % slower and no guarantee of symmetric/Hermitian result
>> isequal(b1,b2)
ans =
  logical
   0
>> isequal(b1',b1)
ans =
  logical
   1
>> isequal(b2',b2)
ans =
  logical
   0
>> max(abs(b1(:)-b2(:))./b1(:))
ans =
   1.0307e-15

Not exactly the same, but pretty darn close. Strict symmetry preserved in b1 but not in b2.
